# Trigger Lambda Function upon Manual Approval of SageMaker Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We use SageMaker to train our ML model. After training, we need to examine the metric and give it a manual approval. Upon approval, we need to copy the model artifects to another AWS account. If we have a Lambda function to copy the artifects, how can we automatically trigger the lambda function upon the model approval?

Answer (score 1):

Model Approval emits an event in EventBridge, you can create a rule that invokes a Lambda function whenever a model's approval status changes.

Here is an example of the event pattern for the rule in EventBridge.

```
{
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Package State Change"],
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail": {
    "ModelPackageGroupName": ["model-package-name"]
    "ModelApprovalStatus": ["Approved"]
  }
}
```

For the rule target, select your Lambda function.